# Unable to add multiple redirect URLs with Microsoft Live OAuth service

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, redirect, windows-live

I have an ASP.Net C# Web Application in which I have added Windows Live oAuth authentication (I am not using the code supplied by the Visual Studio project template  for oAuth). I have two return pages in my application where the user should come back after authenticating with the Windows Live oAuth Service. The reason I have two end points is to distinguish two different modes in my application based on where the user returns.

Anyways, the problem is that when I add the second URL in the configuration screen of Microsoft Windows live at https://account.live.com/developers/applications/apisettings/, the Microsoft Live page simply does not save it. Here is what I am doing:

1. Go to https://account.live.com/developers/applications/index
2. Click Application name and then edit Settings
3. go To API Settings
4. Click "Add another redirect URL"
5. Added my second URL and clicked save.
6. The second text box where I entered the URL simply disappears and my second URL does not work in the oAuth flow.

If any of you has faced a similar issue, do you have a work around? If this is something Microsoft should fix, where should I raise this bug with Microsoft?

[image: Screen shot where I have added the second redirect URL]

[image: Screen shot after clicking on save. See the second text box for redirect URL has disappeared.]

Update: I have also tried a work around of creating two applications, so that each one has one of the return URLs, but Microsoft does not allow two applications with the same root domain URL. :(

Comment: Does the redirect urls both contains the "Root domain" specified ? 
I have a similar issue, where I want to allow redirect urls for different root domain, and windows live doesn't allow it.

Comment: I don't think you can redirect to different root domains within a single application. It kind of beats the specification of the oAuth protocol. You will have to configure another application in live for your second domain.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue.

This is not your fault, and there is nothing other than Microsoft would be able to fix it.

Comment: If you do get any pointers on where to raise this issue to bring it to the attention of MS, then please share. Thanks in advance.